# Couldn't find "Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser.dll" when executing a Powershell script through MSBuild

Tags: c#, sql-server, powershell, msbuild

We have a MSBuild process that currently executes a set of scripts, one of which is a Powershell script that uses some of the SMO tools inside powershell. If I copy and paste the line that MSBuild prints into command prompt, it works perfectly, however whenever MSBuild runs it can't find the assembly.

I have printed environment variables, they are the same so I am assuming it's a property in the `.targets` however for the life of me I can't find a way to print the variable it's scanning for or know where it would be.

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
```

Any ideas or solutions to help, I am stumped?

Answer (score 5):

I’ve got the exactly same problem with version 14. I've edited this answer as I have found the nature of my problem:  msbuild is spawning 32bit powershell where as when I run powershell from "Run" or shortcut it is 64bit.

This is problem reproduced manually:

```
PS C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> [Environment]::Is64BitProcess
False
PS C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> Invoke-Sqlcmd
Invoke-Sqlcmd : Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser, Version=14.100.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-Sqlcmd
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.FileNotFoundException,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand
PS C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0>
```

When I run 64bit version *Invoke-Sqlcmd* works fine:

```
PS C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> [Environment]::Is64BitProcess
True
PS C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> Invoke-Sqlcmd
PS C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0>
```

As you see above, calling Invoke-Sqlcmd is working (not causing exception). 
At this stage I do not know why some 32bit assembly is missing for Sqlcmd.

This is how I call my msbuild project:

```
msbuild -version 2>NUL || CALL "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat"
CALL msbuild build-MYPROJECT.proj /Target:Build
```

One of my targets in msbuild project is calling powershell.exe via **Exec** tag:

```
    <Exec ContinueOnError="False" Command="$(PowerShellExe) .\Scripts\upgrade-projects.ps1 $(SqlServer) '$(TempPath)\$(TemplateProjDb)_$(AssemblyVersion).sql' $(AssemblyVersion)" />
```

The **$(PowerShellExe)** is defined like that:

```
    <PowerShellExe>powershell.exe -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass</PowerShellExe>
```

I've assumed that msbuild will spawn default 64bit powershell. But it does not (for some reason).

*The whole confusion; that cost my whole Saturday ;) is the msbuild project and the scripts are working perfectly fine on my Windows 10 laptop and also on one of the VM machines I use.  When I tried to run on on different development machine (also Windows 10, VS2017, the same extensions packs, all updates etc...)  I did present the problem above.*

So I've tried to change my PowerShellExe to

```
 <PowerShellExe>C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass .\Scripts\concat-scripts.ps1 </PowerShellExe>
```

but it still execute 32bit version.

Now I have to find the reason why msbuild is spawning 32bit powershell on the other machines whereas on my laptop and vm it is default 64bit.

Or simply ... **how to force 32bit msbuild to spawn 64bit powershell ?**

At this point I've tried to run 64bit msbuild (I don't like the full path):

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\amd64\msbuild.exe" build-MYPROJECT.proj
```

and it is spawning 64bit powershell.

That would be my solution if

```
VsDevCmd.bat -arch=amd64 -host_arch=amd64
```

would point automatically to msbuild 64bit... somehow it doesn't.

**The question is still why on one machine 32bit msbuild spawn 64bit powershell and in another doesn't (even I provide full path to 64bit) ?**

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you did? Also, did `invoke-sqlcmd` solve the problem? Your last sentence make it seem like it did not.

Comment: I've added more details as I've found the nature of the problem. Now I have to figure out why msbuild is spawning 32bit powershell on one machine and 64bit on another.

Comment: Had the same issue when using the Teamcity Powershell runner in the build step. Ensure to select the Platform as "x64" in the build step configuration. If using a MetaRunner ensure the setting "jetbrains_powershell_bitness" has the value "x64".

Comment: Old comment, but just wanted to let you know what I found out. Even if you link to the x64 bit version of powershell in postbuild/msbuild, 32bit visual studio or msbuild will still pull in the 32 bit powershell. You have to specify the path like this "
%WINDIR%\SysNative\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" for it to force x64. Notice the "SysNative" alias. That makes sure your System32 isn't translated to syswow. this cost me a Tuesday. I feel your pain.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that Microsoft accidentally included 32-bit packages in both directories.

See the following thread for Charles Gagnon of Microsoft's claim that this will be fixed soon in an update:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/7a71121c-83b1-49b4-ad30-3a5f20e7afbf/smo-2017-microsoftsqlserverbatchparserdll-load-error?forum=sqlsmoanddmo

Still haven't seen the fix though. This seems to be environmental. This does not impact me on all of my environments.

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference: I had the same problem and I wasn't able to fix it with neither of following recommended steps:

- reinstall C++ redistributables
- compile against specific architecture (x84, x64, default AnyCPU)

In my case, I had new PC (W7->W10) with new VS (2017->2019), updated SSMS and simultaneously there was an update on the database server (2016->2019). So rather than trying to find way out of the dependencies, I included dependencies manually, putting binaries of:

- microsoft.sqlserver.batchparser.dll
- Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParserClient.dll

I quickly found the proper files (out of installed dlls found in Program Files folder) by try-and-error and the app is working now. If it was a production app, then the next step would be to add proper reference according to the working dll source.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem when trying to execute Invoke-Sqlcmd within PowerShell script from Visual Studio post-build event. Switching from x86 to x64 within the script solved the problem:

```
if ($env:PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432 -eq "AMD64") {
    Write-Warning "Switching from 32bit to 64bit PowerShell"
    $powershell = Join-Path $PSHOME.ToLower().Replace("syswow64","sysnative").Replace("system32","sysnative") powershell.exe
    if ($myInvocation.Line) {
        &"$powershell" -NonInteractive -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass $myInvocation.Line
    } else {
        &"$powershell" -NonInteractive -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -file "$($myInvocation.InvocationName)" $args
    }

    exit $lastexitcode
}
```

Credits goes to this [blogpost](http://vegetarianprogrammer.blogspot.com/2013/03/running-64-bit-powershell-from-32-bit.html)